# Planck's Energy Density Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to plot the graphs for different temperatures and frequencies in Python, I defined a function, but when I want to plot it, it shows me an error.

```
def planck(v,T):
    h=6.62606957*(10**-34.0)
    c=3*(10**8.0)
    k=1.3806488*(10**-23.0)

    x=(h*8*pi/c**3.0)
    y=v**3
    exponente = (h*v/k*T)
    ex = math.exp(exponente)-1

    PLANCK=(x*y)*(ex**-1)
    return PLANCK

x0, xf, dx = 800,2*(10**8),1000  
X = arange(x0, xf, dx)
print X

P1=planck(X, 3000)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-034ad82af010> in <module>()
----> 1 P1=planck(X, 3000)

<ipython-input-11-e52b9512e92c> in planck(v, T)
      7     y=v**3
      8     exponente = (h*v/k*T)
----> 9     ex = math.exp(exponente)-1
     10 
     11     PLANCK=(x*y)*(ex**-1)

 TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

And then, if I just use `exp` instead of `math.exp`, the graph results a constant.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to using `numpy.exp` instead of `math.exp`, you also need to specify the dtype of `X` to be `float` rather than `int32`. With `int32`, the largest number representable is

```
In [46]: np.iinfo('int32').max
Out[46]: 2147483647
```

and `y=v**3` exceeds this value:

```
In [38]: v
Out[38]: 
array([      800,      1800,      2800, ..., 199997800, 199998800,
       199999800])
In [37]: y
Out[37]: 
array([  512000000, -2147483648, -2147483648, ..., -2147483648,
       -2147483648, -2147483648])
```

Thus the reason why your values look like constants is because of arithmetic overflow.

So change

```
X = np.arange(x0, xf, dx)
```

to

```
X = np.arange(x0, xf, dx, dtype='float')
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
pi = np.pi

def planck(v,T):
    h=6.62606957*(10**-34.0)
    c=3*(10**8.0)
    k=1.3806488*(10**-23.0)

    x=(h*8*pi/c**3.0)
    y=v**3
    exponente = (h*v/k*T)
    ex = np.exp(exponente)-1

    PLANCK=(x*y)*(ex**-1)
    return PLANCK

x0, xf, dx = 800,2*(10**8),1000  
X = np.arange(x0, xf, dx, dtype='float')

P1 = planck(X, 3000)
plt.plot(X, P1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Sven Marnach got the programming bit right, you need to use Numpy `exp`.

As for why you get the constants, you've written your function using SI units. As a result, your input must be in SI units.

You want to divide `X` by `1e9` if your wavelengths were in nanometers. As it stands, you are passing wavelengths of ~800 meters.

Answer (score -1):

Compute the constant values once, then hard-code them, if you need some speed...